# Which FileystemDirectory should I use for a temporary file?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm building an Ionic app with Capacitor, and I need to write a temporary file that I will be uploading to a webservice then deleting.

The [Capacitor Filesystem API](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/filesystem/) uses an object to specify the file to be written or read:

```
Filesystem.writeFile({
    path: 'secrets/text.txt',
    data: "This is a test",
    directory: FilesystemDirectory.Documents,
    encoding: FilesystemEncoding.UTF8
})
```

Capacitor does some cross-platform magic to combine the relative path and the FileSystemDirectory enumeration to create a file appropriate for the platform.

The FileSystemDirectory enumeration:

```
enum FilesystemDirectory {
    // The Application directory
    Application: "APPLICATION"

    // The Cache directory
    Cache: "CACHE"

    // The Data directory
    Data: "DATA"

    // The Documents directory
    Documents: "DOCUMENTS"

    // The external directory (Android only)
    External: "EXTERNAL"

    // The external storage directory (Android only)
    ExternalStorage: "EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
}
```

Which of these, Application, Cache, Data, or Documents would be most appropriate for a temporary file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Cache folder for files that can be recreated as the OS can delete them in cases of low memory.